# How to move the focus smoothly from a TextField to a newly created TextField?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'd like to create a screen in which many `TextFIeld`s lined up vertically, and when the Enter key is pressed while editing the bottom `TextField`, a new `TextField` is added below it moving the focus too. I created a demo app referring to [the example](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Focus-class.html#widgets.Focus.3) in the docs of `FocusNode` and it works basically but the keyboard bounces when moving the focus to a newly created `TextField` (see the gif below). How can I fix this unwanted behavior?

[The gif of the demo app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mrCJ5.gif)

The code of the demo app is here:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  static const String _title = 'Flutter Code Sample';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      title: _title,
      home: MyStatefulWidget(),
    );
  }
}

class MyStatefulWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyStatefulWidget({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyStatefulWidget> createState() => _MyStatefulWidgetState();
}

class _MyStatefulWidgetState extends State<MyStatefulWidget> {
  int focusedChild = 0;
  List<Widget> children = <Widget>[];
  List<FocusNode> childFocusNodes = <FocusNode>[];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    // Add the first child.
    _addChild();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    for (final FocusNode node in childFocusNodes) {
      node.dispose();
    }
    super.dispose();
  }

  void _addChild() {
    // Calling requestFocus here creates a deferred request for focus, since the
    // node is not yet part of the focus tree.
    childFocusNodes
        .add(FocusNode(debugLabel: 'Child ${children.length}')..requestFocus());

    children.add(
      TextField(
        focusNode: childFocusNodes.last,
        textInputAction: TextInputAction.unspecified,
        minLines: 1,
        onSubmitted: (value) {
          setState(() {
            focusedChild = children.length;
            _addChild();
          });
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
            children: children,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0bltG.gif)

You need to use [TextInputAction](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/services/TextInputAction.html)

`TextInputAction.next`: Moves the focus to the next focusable item.

`TextInputAction.done`: To close the keyboard.

---

```
class TestWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const TestWidget({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
          children: const [
            TextField(
              decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: 'TextField #1 with next'),
              textInputAction: TextInputAction.next, // Moves the focus to the next focusable item.
            ),
            TextField(
              decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: 'TextField #2 with next'),
              textInputAction: TextInputAction.next, // Moves the focus to the next focusable item.
            ),
            TextField(
              decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: 'TextField #3 with done'),
              textInputAction: TextInputAction.done, // Close the keyboard.
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

---

## Update

#### Create a new text field on editing complete and change focus to the new one.

1. You need to use `onEditingComplete` function, instead of `onSubmitted`. Because `onEditingComplete`  will not close (dismiss) the keyboard.
2. I rewrite your code, and remove generating a list of widgets. And replaced it with `TextEditingController` because it's a bad experience to keep UI (widgets) in a variable. So text fields generates by `TextEditingController` length.
3. I remove a list of `FocusNode`, and use `FocusScope.of(context).nextFocus()` to change the focus.
4. After creating a new `TextEditingController` function call delayed `nextFocus()` with delay, to give time to recreate the new UI.

*here is the full code:*

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(home: MyStatefulWidget());
  }
}

class MyStatefulWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyStatefulWidget({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyStatefulWidget> createState() => _MyStatefulWidgetState();
}

class _MyStatefulWidgetState extends State<MyStatefulWidget> {
  final List<TextEditingController> _controllers = [
    TextEditingController()
  ]; // with first controller

  _addController() {
    setState(() {
      _controllers.add(TextEditingController());
    });

    Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 100), () {
      // Add delay for recreate UI after setState
      FocusScope.of(context).nextFocus();
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
            children: _controllers
                .map((e) => TextField(
                      textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
                      controller: e,
                      onEditingComplete: _addController,
                    ))
                .toList(),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But what I want to do is to dynamically add a new `TextField` to the bottom of the list, moving the focus as well. `TextInputAction.next` doesn't work for this case because the new `TextField` is not yet attached to the widget tree when the Next key is pressed.

Comment: @fuji sorry, I don't understand your question the first time. Please check, I updated my answer.

Comment: It's nice and much simpler than what I had in mind. I think it would be even better if we use `WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback` instead of `Future.delayed`. Anyway, thanks a lot.